# Fermat's little theorem, Poulet numbers, Carmichael numbers, and primes

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes, fermat-numbers, carmichael-function, carmichael-numbers

Fermat's primality test for base 2 permits Poulet numbers to pass the test, as follows: $(2^x - 2)/x$.  Fermat's primality test in different bases will act as a sieve for eliminating most pseudo primes from passing the test, unless the numbers are Carmichael numbers.

I ran an experiment for the following formula $(5^x - 3^x - 2^x)/x$ and it seems to eliminate all but Carmichael numbers, without having to check different bases.

I was capable of running the experiment until 10000 only (due to my lack of computing calculation power).

Does anyone know about this formula and whether it still holds forever?

Comment: $25326001$ is a (strong) pseudoprime [for the bases $2,3,5$](https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html), thus it will pass your test. But it is [not a Carmichael number](https://oeis.org/A002997/b002997.txt).

Comment: I see. Will that be the smallest number? Thanks,

Comment: I don't know. It's the smallest composite that's a strong pseudoprime to these bases, but there may be a smaller one that's an ordinary Fermat pseudoprime to these bases (without being a Carmichael number). And since you combine the three powers, it is not impossible that deviations cancel where separate tests would show compositeness. Off the top of my head, I'd consider that an unlikely scenario, but without checking I can't tell.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a reason why the combination of 5-3-2 does seem to take care of numbers with other bases like 4,6,7,  ...  (I can confirm it at least until 10000) ?

Comment: I don't think 5-3-2 is special, a lot of $(a+b)^x - a^x - b^x$ should be about equally efficient. Pseudoprimes are rare, and small numbers that are pseudoprimes for several bases tend to be Carmichael numbers (unless the bases are carefully selected). If you check larger numbers, more pseudoprimes that aren't Carmichael numbers should turn up alongside the Carmichael numbers. But that takes more computational power.

Comment: I started another improved question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369430/fermats-little-theorem-poulet-numbers-carmichael-numbers-and-primes

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was answered here (inspired by the comments above): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369430/fermats-little-theorem-poulet-numbers-carmichael-numbers-and-primes
Yes the formula is known and yes there are smaller numbers than 25326001.